# Alternatives after Dropbox Sync API is removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, cloud-storage

We've been using the Dropbox Sync API in our iOS app for the last couple of years. This API allows us to treat the user's Dropbox folder like a second file system, making it simple to access the contents. It also downloads and uploads new versions of files automatically, so we have to do very little work other than hooking it into our application. In short, it's a nice API that abstracted away all the "difficult bits" (file caching, etc) that was a pleasure for us to use.

Unfortunately, Dropbox are turning off the Sync API at the end of June, so we need to find an alternative. Moving to the new Dropbox "v2 API" would require us to reimplement the "difficult bits" of the old Sync API to provide the same functionality to users, so we're looking for alternatives in case there's a simpler solution.

Are there APIs to allow an app to access the user's Google Drive or OneDrive files, that are as simple to use as the old Dropbox Sync API? Ideally I want the API to handle all the caching automatically, so that we only have to say "open file X" or "overwrite file Y", and have it handle all the difficult bits (do I check the server for a new version of the file? What if I'm offline? Do I have a cached version saved here already? etc).

Or is that an outdated model, and we should just plan to use Apple's UIDocumentPicker API instead, to allow access to whatever cloud services the user has installed on their device?

Comment: Does the [CloudRail abstraction layer](https://cloudrail.com/unified-cloud-storage-api/) help?

Comment: It looks like that wraps the basic APIs for upload/download/etc, but doesn't provide any out-of-the-box caching of stuff?